# Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connection closed Error Code: 0

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

We have a java web application deployed into payara 164 application Server.
Host machine is a debian 9.3 server, used database is a mariadb-server-10.1, java version is "1.8.0_131".

Recently we are facing some problems related to Connection.

During a longer procedure, the invocation of the below query:

```
UPDATE mailboxes SET mb_last_receive_run = ? WHERE (mb_id = ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
```

yields:

> Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
>   Error Code: 0

Comment: Have you tried increasing the wait_timeout? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: The error suggests you are using a connection after it has been closed. Without a [mcve] we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. First step update your timeout settings in your application server. make sure your request supports transaction if not initiate a transaction they start the process.
2. Maybe you are running this method at least twice at the same time (in separate threads / async tasks). And then you close the connection at the end of the method while in an other thread the method hasn't finished yet